# Composition of continuous linear maps is also a continuous linear map

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis

Let $V, W , X$ be normed spaces and let $T \colon V \to W$ and $ S \colon W \to X$ be continuous linear maps. show that $ S \circ T \colon V \to X$ is a continuous linear map and that $||S \circ T || \leq ||S||||T||$

I know that showing a linear map is continuous is equivalent to showing that it is bounded but i cannot seem to find any bounds. (But im not sure about this approach as thats what the second part of the question asks).

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that $\|Ax\| \leq \|A\|\|x\|$ for any continuous linear map $A$ and any vector $x$?

Answer (score 1):

$F$ is continuous iff the pre-image of any open image is open.  This should help with the continuity. For linearity of the map use the definition of linear map. $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y),\ x,y$ are vectors and $f(ax)=af(x)$ for $a\in F$.

Comment: Is this analogous to a proof of if $f : V \to W$ ,$g : W \to X$ are continuous functions then $g \circ f$ is continuous? (This is a proof i have, which im just going to adjust slightly)